# How to make entire <tr> row clickable in laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am trying to make whole row (tr) clickable in table. Here is the code I have tired,

```
<table class="container">
   <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><h1>Id</h1></th>
        <th><h1>Number</h1></th>
        <th><h1>Type</h1></th>
        <th><h1>Value</h1></th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
        @for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
        <tr class="table-tr" data-url="http://www.engineering.us/gena/details.php">     
          <td>{{ $data_array[$i]['id'] }}</td>
          <td>{{ $data_array[$i]['number'] }}</td>
          <td>{{ $data_array[$i]['name'] }}</td>
          <td>{{ $data_array[$i]['value'] }}</td>       
       </tr>
@endfor     
 </tbody>
```

`

And the JS Script,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $(".container").on("click", "tr[data-url]", function () {
      window.location = $(this).data("url");
    });
  });
</script>
```

It is not working. Please tell how can we do this.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `.on("click", ".table-tr")`?

Comment: `$("table.container tbody tr").click(function () {`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. it is not working friends. i dont have any errors  in console also.

Comment: $(document).on("click", "tr[data-url]", function () {
    window.location = $(this).data("url");
});

Comment: I posted the answer it is what exactly you needed, accept the answer if it helped

Comment: Thanks @msonowal .. It worked :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  $('table.container').on("click", "tr.table-tr", function() {
    window.location = $(this).data("url");
    //alert($(this).data("url"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="container">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <h1>Id</h1></th>
      <th>
        <h1>Number</h1></th>
      <th>
        <h1>Type</h1></th>
      <th>
        <h1>Value</h1></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="table-tr" data-url="http://www.engineering.us/gena/details.php">
      <td>id</td>
      <td>number</td>
      <td>manash</td>
      <td>28</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```